# cURL: Get the error message

Tags: shell-script, curl

I've made a little bash script to monitor some websites and mail server with cURL.

I'd check the HTTP Status Code and Exit Code. But I'd like to include the actual error message from cURL as well. Can't figure out how to put it all together.

The following code is what I currently have:

```
RESPONSE=$(curl --location --head --silent --output /dev/null --write-out '%{response_code}' nohosthere.com ; echo " $?")
R=( $RESPONSE )
CODE="${R[0]}"
EXIT="${R[1]}"


if [ $CODE -eq 200 ]; then
    echo 'Ok'
else
    echo "Response: ${RESPONSE}"
    echo "Code: ${CODE}"
    echo "Exit: ${EXIT}"
    #echo "MESSAGE I WANT HERE curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nohosthere.com"
fi
```

When I add the *--show-error* it is printed out directly. I can redirect it to a file or sterr but have no idea to get all together.

I know --write_out has something like *%{errormsg}* and *%{exitcode}* but both are not available at my test system (macOS 10.15) nor at my AWS Lightsail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just `RESPONSE=$(...)` (without the `echo $?` at the end), and then `EXIT=$?` ?

You don't need an array for this - `$RESPONSE` will contain the output of `curl` and `$EXIT` will contain the exit code.

Comment: Thanks, that makes totally sense and seems so easy :-) I am not good at Bash scripting and only do one or two scripts per year. Unfortunately, because I like to but have no practical use cases.